# TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class '__main__.MainWindow'>, 'QMainWindow'))

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt5, qt-designer

This is my 'main.py' code:

```
    ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
    
    flag  = 0
    GLOBAL_STATE = False
    GLOBAL_TITLE_BAR = True
    
    
    
    from dashboard import Ui_MainWindow
    
    
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
                QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            # self.ui.setupUi(self)
                self.ui = uic.loadUi("untitled.ui", self)
                self.progressBarValue(0)
                self.progress()
                
                self.distance_percent = 0
                self.traces = dict()
                
                self.timestamp = 0
                self.timeaxis = []
                self.distanceaxis = []
                self.current_timer_graph = None
                # self.csv_file = open(datafile, 'w')
                # self.csv_writer = csv.writer(self.csv_file, delimiter=',')
                
                self.graph_lim = 15
                self.deque_timestamp = deque([], maxlen=self.graph_lim+20)
                self.deque_distance = deque([], maxlen=self.graph_lim+20)
                
                
    
                ## REMOVE TITLE BAR
                self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
                self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
                
                self.graphwidget1 = PlotWidget(title="Distance percent")
                x1_axis = self.graphwidget1.getAxis('bottom')
                x1_axis.setLabel(text='Time since start (s)')
                y1_axis = self.graphwidget1.getAxis('left')
                y1_axis.setLabel(text='Percent')
                self.show_distance_graph()
                self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphwidget1, 0, 0, 1, 3)
                self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
                self.timer.start(0)
                self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.slideanimation(400, True))
                self.timer.timeout.connect(self.progress)
                self.ui.max_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.maximize_restore())
                self.ui.close_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close_window())
                self.ui.min_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.min_window())
                
                self.show()
    
        
    
        def show_distance_graph(self):
            
            self.graphwidget1.show()
            self.start_distance_graph()
            
        def start_distance_graph(self, value):
            if self.current_timer_graph:
                self.current_timer_graph.stop()
                self.current_timer_graph.deleteLater()
                self.current_timer_graph = None
            self.current_timer_graph = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.current_timer_graph.timeout.connect(self.update_distance)
            self.current_timer_graph.start(0)
        def update_distance(self, value):
            
            self.deque_timestamp.append(self.timestamp)
            self.deque_distance.append(value)
            self.deque_ram.append(self.ram_percent)
            timeaxis_list = list(self.deque_timestamp)
            cpu_list = list(self.deque_distance)
    
            if self.timestamp > self.graph_lim:
                self.graphwidget1.setRange(xRange=[self.timestamp-self.graph_lim+1, self.timestamp], yRange=[
                                           min(cpu_list[-self.graph_lim:]), max(cpu_list[-self.graph_lim:])])
            self.set_plotdata(name="distance", data_x=timeaxis_list,
                              data_y=cpu_list)
        
        def set_plotdata(self, name, data_x, data_y):
            # print('set_data')
            if name in self.traces:
                self.traces[name].setData(data_x, data_y)
            else:
                if name == "distance":
                    self.traces[name] = self.graphwidget1.getPlotItem().plot(
                        pen=pg.mkPen((85, 170, 255), width=3))
    
    
    
    
        
    
            
        def min_window(self):
            self.showMinimized()
        def close_window(self):
            self.close()
            sys.exit()
        def maximize_restore(self):
            global GLOBAL_STATE
            status = GLOBAL_STATE
            if status == False:
                self.showMaximized()
                GLOBAL_STATE = True
                self.ui.Background.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                self.ui.max_button.setToolTip("Restore")
                ##self.ui.maximizeRestoreAppBtn.setIcon(QIcon(u":/icons/images/icons/icon_restore.png"))
                ##self.ui.frame_size_grip.hide()
                ##self.left_grip.hide()
                ##self.right_grip.hide()
                ##self.top_grip.hide()
                ##self.bottom_grip.hide()
            else:
                GLOBAL_STATE = False
                self.showNormal()
                self.resize(self.width()+1, self.height()+1)
                self.ui.Background.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
                self.ui.max_button.setToolTip("Maximize")
                ##self.ui.maximizeRestoreAppBtn.setIcon(QIcon(u":/icons/images/icons/icon_maximize.png"))
                ##self.ui.frame_size_grip.show()
                ##self.left_grip.show()
                ##self.right_grip.show()
                ##self.top_grip.show()
                ##self.bottom_grip.show()
    
    
        def slideanimation(self, maxWidth, enable):
            if enable:
                
                print("click")
                slider_style = """
        QSlider::groove {
            border: 1px solid rgba(38, 38, 38,{Grove_Border_trans});
            width: 5px;
            background: rgba(56, 2, 88,{Grove_Back_trans});
            margin: 0 16px;
        }
    
        QSlider::handle {
            background: rgba(255, 148, 0,{handle_Back_trans});
            border: 2px solid rgba(114, 4, 231,{handle_Border_trans});
            height: 20px;
            margin: -5px -5px;
                border-radius: 7px;
        }
    
        """
                width = self.ui.Widgetholder.width()
                Grove_Border = Grove_Back = handle_Back = handle_Border = str(255)
                standard = 351
                if width == 351:
                    newwidth = maxWidth
                    
                else:
                    newwidth = standard
                    ##print(width)
                    ##print("C")
                    ##print(newwidth)
                self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.Widgetholder, b"minimumWidth")
                self.animation.setDuration(400)
                self.animation.setStartValue(width)
                self.animation.setEndValue(newwidth)
                self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
                self.animation.start()
    
                newSlidersheet = slider_style.replace("{Grove_Border_trans}", Grove_Border).replace("{Grove_Back_trans}", Grove_Back).replace("{handle_Back_trans}", handle_Back).replace("{handle_Border_trans}", handle_Border)
                self.ui.verticalSlider.setStyleSheet(newSlidersheet)
            
             
    
        def oxygencircle(self):
            oxygenstylesheet = """
    
             QFrame
            {
            border-radius: 115px;
                    background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:{oxy_1} rgba(0, 255, 251, 0), stop:{oxy_2} rgba(255, 148, 0, 255));
                    
                    
            }
            """
            slider_value = self.ui.verticalSlider.value()
            intslider_value = int(slider_value)
            level = (100-intslider_value)/100.0
    
            Oxy_1 = str(level-0.001)
            Oxy_2 = str(level)
            print(Oxy_1)
            print("C")
            print(Oxy_2)
    
            if level == 100:
                Oxy_1 = "1.000"
                Oxy_2 = "1.000"
    
            newoxystyle = oxygenstylesheet.replace("{oxy_1}", Oxy_1).replace("{oxy_2}", Oxy_2)
            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(newoxystyle)
        
            
        def progress(self):
            
               
                    
                if self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.slideanimation(400, True)):
                   self.oxygencircle()
                
                
                #print("A")
                
                b = ser.readline()# read a byte string
                string_n = b.decode()  # decode byte string into Unicode  
                string = string_n.rstrip() # remove \n and \r
                value = float(string)
                
                if value >= 100:
                    value=100
                update_distance(value)
                if value>12:
                # HTML Text and colour above threshold value
                    text_stylesheet ="""
                                         background-color:none;
                                            color:{change}
    
                                      """
                    htmltext = """{VALUE}"""
                    new_color = "#c10003"
                    #Replace number
                    newstyle=text_stylesheet.replace("{change}", new_color)
                    newHtml = htmltext.replace("{VALUE}", str(int(value)))
                    self.ui.label.setText(newHtml)
                    self.ui.label.setStyleSheet(newstyle)
                    self.progressBarValue(value)
                else:
                # HTML Text and colour under threshold
                    text_stylesheet ="""
                                         background-color:none;
                                            color:{change}
    
                                      """
                    htmltext = """{VALUE}"""
                    new_color = "#ffffff"
                    #Replace number
                    newstyle=text_stylesheet.replace("{change}", new_color)
                    newHtml = htmltext.replace("{VALUE}", str(int(value)))
                    self.ui.label.setText(newHtml)
                    self.ui.label.setStyleSheet(newstyle)
                    self.progressBarValue(value)
    
    
    
    
    
    
        def progressBarValue(self, value):
            styleSheet = """
            QFrame{
        
    border-radius: 110px;
        
    background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:90, stop:{STOP_1} rgba(255, 0, 127, 0), stop:{STOP_2} rgba({color_1}, {color_2}, {color_3}, 255));
        
        
    }
            """
            
            if value>12:
                colour1=str(204)
                colour2=str(0)
                colour3=str(0)
                ##print("value ", value)
                progress = (100-value)/100.0
                stop_1 = str(progress - 0.001)
                stop_2 = str(progress)
                ##print(stop_1)
                ##print(stop_2)
                newStylesheet = styleSheet.replace("{STOP_1}", stop_1).replace("{STOP_2}", stop_2).replace("{color_1}", colour1).replace("{color_2}", colour2).replace("{color_3}", colour3)
                
                self.ui.CircularProgressBar.setStyleSheet(newStylesheet)
                ##print("G")
            else:
                colour1=str(85)
                colour2=str(85)
                colour3=str(255)
                ##print("value ", value)
                progress = (100-value)/100.0
                stop_1 = str(progress - 0.001)
                stop_2 = str(progress)
                ##print(stop_1)
                ##print(stop_2)
                newStylesheet = styleSheet.replace("{STOP_1}", stop_1).replace("{STOP_2}", stop_2).replace("{color_1}", colour1).replace("{color_2}", colour2).replace("{color_3}", colour3)
                
                self.ui.CircularProgressBar.setStyleSheet(newStylesheet)
               ## print("G")
    

    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MainWindow()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the error showing up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\Projects\Hover + Graph\main.py", line 347, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\Projects\Hover + Graph\main.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.ui = uic.loadUi("untitled.ui", self)
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 66, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1037, in parse
    actor(elem)
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 822, in createUserInterface
    self.toplevelWidget = self.createToplevelWidget(cname, wname)
  File "C:\Users\PAVILION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 59, in createToplevelWidget
    (type(self.toplevelInst), classname)))
TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class '__main__.MainWindow'>, 'QMainWindow'))
```

I have put QMainWindow as the base class yet I am getting an error, how to solve this.

Comment: That's a lot of code for people to wade through to try to understand your question. Could you create a minimal working example that illustrates the problem, without all the other code that is not necessary to solve the problem?

Comment: Also, could you include the .ui file in your post?

Comment: please provide a [mre]